# Is the order of an element of a group necessarily a prime?

Tags: group-theory

Let $a$ be an element in a group, $G$. 
Suppose the element $a$ has order $n$.
$$|a|=n$$
Is the order n necessarily a prime number?

Comment: No, any n is possible (consider Z/nZ for example).

Comment: Every group has an element of order one. Is $1$ a prime number?

Answer (score 3):

Nope, consider a cyclic group of order $n$, $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$, additively. 1 has order n.

Answer (score 2):

No.  For example, consider the cyclic group of 4 elements...the generator has order 4.

Answer (score 0):

No why would it be prime consider for example $/mathbb{C}$, $i$ has order $4$ since $i^4$ is the smallest number such that $i^n = 1$ and 4 is not prime. Altough this on the side line one cool way to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ - {$\phi$} and $\mathbb{C}$ - {$\phi$} can never be isomorphic is that |i| = 4 and R doesn't have any element of order $4$ and we know that isomorphism respects order of elements.

Maybe what you meant was suppose that $|G| = p$, where $p$ is prime then suppose $G$ has an element $a$ of order $n$, then must n be prime the answer to this question is yes also in particular that element a will have order $p$.

Hint: (you can use first isomorphism theorem to prove it and the fact that order of element is same as cylic group generated by that element).